# AngularJS provider: chaining methods with unique configs

Tags: angularjs

I have a provider, which has a few methods. My simplified code:

```
this.$get = function () {
    function $service () {
        var service = {};

        function log (word) {
            service.config = word;
            return service;
        }

        function say () {
            console.log(service.config);
            return service;
        }

        service.config = new Config(); // just some prototyped configuration
        service.log = angular.bind(service, log);
        service.say = angular.bind(service, say);
        return service;
    }

    return $service;
};
```

So the idea to have something similar to:

```
  var week = $service;
  var Monday = week.log('Today is Monday.');
  var Tuesday = Monday.log('Today is Tuesday.');
  var Friday = Tuesday.log('Today is Friday.');
```

Which would result:

```
Monday.say(); // 'Today is Monday.'
Tuesday.say(); // 'Today is Tuesday.'
Friday.say(); // 'Today is Friday.'
```

So that each variable would save it's present configuration, but only change when changed method is applied.

For now, I get this:

```
Monday.say(); // 'Today is Friday.'
Tuesday.say(); // 'Today is Friday.'
Friday.say(); // 'Today is Friday.'
```

So the config is overridden every time.

Comment: I'm not sure how your code is working since `.log` doesn't return anything so `Monday`, `Tuesday` and `Friday` would all be undefined.

Comment: Did you try var Tuesday = week.log('Today is Tuesday.');

Comment: This is just a simple example, it's not my real code. But the idea is to have chained methods but each method would hold a personal configuration. So that if you save variable "first = week.log('First')", and later use the saved variable but add something saving it to a different variable "second = first.log('Second')", each "first" and "second" would have different .say() return. So individual configuration would be saved, but because they're chained, they also have a shared configuration.

Comment: But you are updating the same `config` each time

Comment: So that's why I ask how to create additional personal config each time a method is chained.